# Drop the oracle job scheduler after completing the job action

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, scheduler, job-scheduling

I have created one oracle job scheduler which drop one table. After that I want to immediately drop that job scheduler. So, I have written the `DROP_JOB` command in that scheduler only, but getting error object is not exist. This error is coming because I have not created job scheduler yet and trying to drop the same scheduler. Suggest other way to do this task. I don't want to drop the job scheduler manually.

Please refer below code :-

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
        job_name => '"SAPSMC"."V"',
        job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
        job_action => 'BEGIN 
                       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ''DROP TABLE STUDENT'';
                       END;',
        number_of_arguments => 0,
        start_date => NULL,
        repeat_interval => NULL,
        end_date => NULL,
        enabled => FALSE,
        auto_drop => FALSE,
        comments => '');

 DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_JOB(
 job_name         => 'V',
 defer            => TRUE,
 commit_semantics => 'TRANSACTIONAL');



DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE( 
         name => '"SAPSMC"."V"', 
         attribute => 'logging_level', value => DBMS_SCHEDULER.LOGGING_OFF);
DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE( 
         name => '"SAPSMC"."V"', 
         attribute => 'raise_events', value => '32');



DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable(
         name => '"SAPSMC"."V"');
END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code. You have to make the `auto_drop` attribute to `true`.

Reference : [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm)

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
        job_name => '"SAPSMC"."V"',
        job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
        job_action => 'BEGIN 
                       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ''DROP TABLE STUDENT'';
                       END;',
        number_of_arguments => 0,
        start_date => NULL,
        repeat_interval => NULL,
        end_date => NULL,
        enabled => FALSE,
        auto_drop => TRUE,
        comments => '');


DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE( 
         name => '"SAPSMC"."V"', 
         attribute => 'logging_level', value => DBMS_SCHEDULER.LOGGING_OFF);
DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE( 
         name => '"SAPSMC"."V"', 
         attribute => 'raise_events', value => '32');



DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable(
         name => '"SAPSMC"."V"');
END;
```